# … was rejected as an implicit dependency for '…' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, kobold2d

I am trying to build my app in release mode but I keep getting these warnings and I can't seem to figure out how to fix them.

```
chipmunk-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libchipmunk-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
cocos2d-extensions-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
kobold2d-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libkobold2d-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
chipmunk-spacemanager-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
cocos2d-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libcocos2d-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
box2d-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libbox2d-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
cocos3d-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libcocos3d-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
objectal-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libobjectal-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
cocosdenshion-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libcocosdenshion-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
sneakyinput-ios was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libsneakyinput-ios.a' because its architectures 'armv6 armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
```

I am building my project using kobold2d 1.1.3 and cocos2d cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b

Comment: you have to add armv7s to all targets as valid architecture. You may have to remove armv6 because it's no longer supported by Xcode

Comment: I already have that added to all targets, but I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 12):

Try to set `Build active architecture only` to `NO`.

Comment: For me what worked was setting it to No for Debug and Yes for Release.

Comment: I deleted this value and suddenly Xcode could compile. Before I was only getting build failed, because Pods did not have all valid architectures.

Comment: What @Guy said, but the other way: Yes for Debug, No for Release.

Answer (score 3):

If you have those libraries (libchipmunk-ios.a, libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a, ...) as is, then they are missing architecture armv7s: contact your library sources for additional architecture support.

If you are building those libraries from source, then you need to configure each sub-project Build Settings to target $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) Architectures instead of just old armv6 and armv7.